# Is it worth to show/hide existing form over creating new form every time?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, visual-studio

*Imagine we have*:
1) some parent **MainForm**;
2) some child **NewItemForm** (called often).

*What I think is*: why would I use **new NewItemForm()** every time I need the form if I could create it once and set it's **Visible** property to true/false after on need (clearing the previous input ofc).

*What I would want to know*: personally I did not notice any difference however my sketchy knowledges tell me there should be some (memory allocation, controls initialization); support me please with your skill in 
my doubts.

Comment: You should have a very good reason to use that hide/show pattern. This could possibly lead to very subtle errors against the predefined path of initialization of the form. But again this is probably an opinion and the context in which you call and use your  form matters a lot more than a choosen pattern.

Comment: Suppose there are the **textBox** and **Apply/Cancel** buttons for trivial string input: Apply is hit -> textBox.Text is passed to parent.

Comment: .Net framework does all the memory allocation, cleanup and garbage collecting for you. Also, Hardware resources in modern computers are more than enough. So technically there is no big difference. But I think it is better to create new every time.

Answer (score 0):

If the child controls are more or some third party controls pasted on the Winforms then it will take some seconds to load/initialize the form. If there is no control pasted or only .net controls then it is okay. Otherwise it will have performance issue while painting hide and show.